# Why ListPlot3D does not plot specific triangles?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I need to plot o large number of triangles. It happens that some of them do not show up.
**Why?**
(version 10.3.1)

If I exec this, I got no data plotted:

```
ListPlot3D[{{10, 10, 0}, {30, 30, 0}, {10, 10, 500}}]
```

If I exec this, the data is plotted!

```
ListPlot3D[{{10, 10, 0}, {30, 30, 0}, {10.001, 10, 500}}]
```

I'm using *Mathematica* for 15 years now and I'm really tired of those kind of bugs.

Comment: This is the expected behavior: You're basically specifying two z values for `{10,10}`. If you really want to plot triangles, you should use [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html) with [`Polygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html)

Comment: Properties and relations / #4 -> "When using multiple z values for each x, y value, the duplicates are discarded by ListPlot3D"

Answer (score 2):

```
Graphics3D[
 Polygon[
  {
   {10, 10, 0},
   {30, 30, 0},
   {10, 10, 500}
   }
  ]
 , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

<sub>Code and plots done in *Mathemathica 11.1.1* on Win7</sub>